# POST em ReactJS com object incluso, como fazer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, react

Preciso fazer um cadastro de Instrutores de curso, no qual, cada instrutor terá um curso. Como faço?

Estou fazendo dessa forma e não está indo:

**PS.:** a variavel name e email recebem uma variavel em `String`, ja a variavel curso recebe o objeto curso.

**Código:**

```
cadastraInstrutor(name, email, curso) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/instrutores/',{
        method: "POST",
        body: {name: name, email: email, curso: curso},
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
}
```

Após chamar a função cadastrarInstrutor, ele me dá o erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

especificamente ao tentar salvar a variavel curso

Comment: É a mesma pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321765 ? Ou dúvida diferente?

Comment: Já estou conseguindo cadastrar o curso, mas o instrutor precisa, em suas definições ter o objeto curso. Não estou sabendo como fazer isso.

Comment: Ele tá me retornando esse erro: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: Na [**documentação**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) da *MDN* tem alguns [**exemplos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) ... Mas seria bom colocar na pergunta quando esta retornando esse erro, pois aparentemente você esta tentando acessar o retorno.

Comment: Como está seu servidor?

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify({...}),`

Comment: Sua duvida já é outra, acho que seria interessante fechar essa perguntar e fazer uma nova com suas duvidas!